# Белая Африка пишется иначе, чем Чёрная (прописная-строчная)?

Tags: прописная-строчная, топонимика

> ...Не американка – слишком воспитанна – и точно не англичанка. Слишком
>   простодушна для жены фермера. Беззащитна для герцогини. Непригодна в
>   преподавательницы. Оттого я подумала – старая белая Африка. Там чуть
>   дольше протянуло мелкое дворянство. Но наша Миссис оказалась из
>   Австралии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книжках, находимых гуглом, обычно пишется с маленькой. Термин условный: иногда (по антропологическому признаку) подразумеваются северные территории, а иногда - белые поселенцы разных мест.

Comment: О Белой Африке, существовавшей задолго до нашей эры и не вписывающейся в традиционную научную парадигму, об истории открытия и освоения Черного континента, о современных российско-африканских отношениях и о многом другом рассказывает советский и российский писатель, журналист, публицист, переводчик, путешественник-африканист Николай Непомнящий - https://matveychev-oleg.livejournal.com/7995273.html

Comment: Древнее население Северной Африки было преимущественно кавказоидным с незначительной примесью негроидов и представителей древней капоидной (койсанской) расы. Некоторые этнографы и антропологи даже употребляют в этой связи термин «Белая Африка». https://culture.wikireading.ru/11998

Comment: Но автор не хочет прописной, даже не взирая на скриншоты из книг: термин, автор - Вёльфель, Белая - как противоположность субсахарской части континета с негроидным населением... СПАСИБО.