# "И на вид не скажешь"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

> А потолки-то здесь о-го-го. Больше пяти метров. И стены все добротные,
>   и **на вид не скажешь**, какая несущая.

*По виду?* Или и так хорошо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно было бы "**по** виду" (*по какому признаку* выносится суждение). "**На** вид" - нужно прямо называть качество: *на вид она **была** такая-то*.

Comment: И сюда приди - пропадаю! https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448672/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%90%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F